# Nexus - proxy repositories with no indexes?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-indexer

I'm trying to add a proxy to a public repository (specifically [camel-extra](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/camel-extra/wiki/AddingMavenRepo)).  However, I get the following error in my Nexus logs:

*Cannot fetch remote index for repository camel-extra*

and then further down:

*The remoteURL we requested does not exists on remote server (remoteUrl="http://camel-extra.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/releases/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties")*

I've ensured that 'Download Remote Indexes' is 'True', repaired the index, updated the index, all to no avail.  Browsing to the provided URL shows that the artifacts are there.

So if a repository doesn't have this file, is it not proxy-able through Nexus?

TIA,
Roy

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers everyone - was able to pull the artifacts without the index.  Thanks again!

Comment: Could you be please so kind and tell us _how_ you have been able to configure the repository without the remote index download? Your selected answer does not answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repositories without indexes published will be still proxy-able thru Nexus (or any other MRM). Index is only a "topping" providing useful extras like searching the whole remote content, etc.

The index does not participate in proxy-ing at all, hence the lack of it on remote does not affect main functionality of Nexus at all: to proxy artifacts from remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

From the nexus [documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-manage-repo.html), it appears that downloading an index is configurable.

> The default for new proxy repositories
>   is enabled, but all of the default
>   repositories included in Nexus have
>   this option disabled.

You should disable the Downloading of Remote Index.

Comment: @Roy.  Why would you want to download a remote index which does not exist?  All you want is to proxy the remote repository which is still possible with nexus.  Others have pointed out the same.

Comment: link to documentation is broken

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is proxyable. Just try to download an artifact which is hosted in that repository. The indexes only affect searching and the index published in turn by Nexus.

Comment: This no longer seems to work out of the box for me.  Using Nexus 2.14.4-03 - when I try to download anything from https://simulation.tudelft.nl/maven/ it doesn't pull it down.